# \hrulefill vertical centering

Tags: spacing, resume

I am creating a resume in latex, and for each section I write the section name + \hrulefill to have a line coming after the section name to the end of the page.

\hrulefill works nicely, but by default the line goes along the bottom of the line it sits on. This is fine, but I would like it to be raised slightly higher, as to make it look like the line is coming out of the middle of the section.

For example, right now it looks like:
WORK EXPERIENCE________(end of page)

I want it to look like:
WORK EXPERIENCE--------(end of page)

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can use the `xhfill` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    WORK EXPERIENCE\xrfill[3pt]{2pt}
    
    WORK EXPERIENCEEE\xrfill[0.275\baselineskip]{0.5pt}
    
    work experience\xrfill[0.175\baselineskip]{0.5pt}
    
    WORK EXPERIENCEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE\xdotfill[0.275\baselineskip]{0.5pt}
    
    WORK EXPERIENCEEEEEE\xrfill[3pt]{3pt}[blue]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!

Comment: Please accept the answer that helped  you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

The standard `\hrule` has height 0.4pt and depth 0pt. You can move it up by giving it a bigger height and a negative depth so that the sum of height and depth remains 0.4pt:

```tex
\line{Work Experience\leaders\hrule height3pt depth-2.6pt\hfill}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!