# How to raise a horizontal line?

Tags: vertical-alignment, rules

I am trying to draw a horizontal line to the right of some text and to the end of the page, but as the text lengths are variable, I have opted to use `\hrulefill` instead of `\rule` so that the length of the horizontal line drawn is calculated automatically.

For example, MWE 1 below shows how the default `\hrulefill` works.

**MWE 1**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hi \hrulefill

Hello \hrulefill

\end{document}
```

Subsequently, I wanted to customise its thickness and found some code to do it. In particular, MWE 2 below changes the line's thickness from a default of 0.4 pt to 1.5 pt.

**MWE 2**

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\hrulefill}{%
    \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1.5 pt\hfill\kern 0 pt}

\begin{document}

Hi \hrulefill

Hello \hrulefill

\end{document}
```

Finally, I would like the line to be drawn from the centre of the words i.e. slightly higher than what the above MWEs produce. Thus, I was wondering how I could further adapt the `\renewcommand` code to include how "high" the line is drawn as well.

I note that a similar question has been asked and some solutions have been given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309632/raise-or-lower-hrulefill), but I am hoping to find a solution that simply adapts the `\renewcommand` code above!

Any intuitive explanations or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664583/hrulefill-vertical-centering/664584#664584

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Oh, yes it does! Thank you! But since an answer has been given too, I think I'll accept that as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules also have a third field (along with their width and height), their depth. A negative depth will raise the rule. Specifically, a rule with a depth of `d` and a height of `h` will seem to be lowered by `d` and have a width of `h+d`.
Thus you can change your definition to:

```latex
\renewcommand{\hrulefill}[2][0pt]{%
    \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height \dimexpr#1+#2\relax depth -#1\hfill\kern0pt}
```

This creates `\hrulefill` which accepts its width as its mandatory parameter and how much it is raised as its optional parameter.